# Want HTML button to send email with input details

Tags: html, email, button, input, send

Where did it go wrong? I want this button to send email to me with name and email address.

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@email.com" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="subscriberName">name</label>
   <input type="text" name="subscriberName" class="center-block form-control" placeholder="name" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="subscriberEmail">email</label>
    <input type="email" name="subscriberEmail" class="center-block form-control form-subs-email" placeholder="email" />
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you passing the data? You need PHPmailer or similar to send the actual form.

Answer (score 0):

Action needs to be prefaced with `mailto:`

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@email.com" class="form-inline">
```

*Also, thanks. I didn't know you could do that.*

Comment: Oh I must have forgotten to add that when i edited my real email adress, it still doesn't work sadly :/ I read somewhere that "value="Send Email" was added, it didnt seem to work for me though :/

Comment: With all due respect, that is not a compatible solution. Unless you seriously plan on only using it to literally email yourself and not impliment on a live site?

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm here for! I would greatly apprechiate a better solution for my need.

Comment: @norcaljohnny Do you know the use case or are you speculating?

Comment: @MicahWilliamson- Respectfully, what's there to speculate?  mailto: invokes the email client to send the form through an email app that has been set up. Some systems will not even alert the user that their email app is not configured to send emails. So, they think they sent an email, and in turn it was not sent nor will they get a reply, if required. But as for the OP, he answered yesterday, that it does not work for his need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really wanting to go this route. The issue is in your first line of code. It should look more like this.

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@email.com?subject=newSubscriber" class="form-inline" enctype="text/plain"  method="post">
```

Demo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/ss3vwr0u/)

**Planning to send an HTML form 2 Email?**

Things to know.

**Is there an HTML Code to send email from a form submission?**

There is no feature in HTML to send the form submission directly to an email address.

**What about “mailto” ?**

Using mailto:
You can set the action field of the form as ‘mailto’. In this case, the web browser invokes the email client to send the form submission to the email address specified.

However, this method is not compatible across browsers. It is not user friendly too; on form submission, it throws a warning message. For more details on this method, see:
email form using

**Can JavaScript send the form submission to an email address?**

No. JavaScript can’t do email either. If the client-side JavaScript allowed sending email programmatically, spammers will be the first to exploit it and you will hate your web browser!

**So, How to get email from an HTML form?**

Before jumping into the solution, I will take you through the general structure of a web form. A web form has two parts: the front-end of the form that you see in your browser and a back-end script that runs on the web server.

Your web browser displays the Form using the HTML front-end code. When you submit the form, the browser sends the information you submitted in the form to the back-end.

**To learn how to do so, I suggest reading up on it here. http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/html-email-form.html**

[image]